# How can I avoid decimals in a number value that is shown with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, audio, innerhtml

The code is for an audio system when the user presses Up arrow or Down arrow then the volume changing with 0.05 up or down (5%) on the audio volume. That code isn't important. I just said because the changing value is 0.05 that means when I want to display the current volume the numbers sometimes look like this:

A good one:[image]

A bad one: [image]

Anything I could use? Maybe RegEx? (but how) Here is the code:

```
Element.innerHTML = "Hangerő: <strong>" + (audio_element.volume * 100) + "%</strong>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try parseInt() .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```
Element.innerHTML = "Hangerő: <strong>" + parseInt(audio_element.volume * 100) + "%</strong>"
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! but the numers still in ex.: 49 not 50

Comment: Ok. Use [Math.round()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) instead of parseInt()